# Caption below thumbnails (wordpress lightbox gallery)

Tags: wordpress, gallery, thumbnails, caption

I'm using a wordpress plugin (lightbox gallery) where you can choose to use highslide for your photo galleries, but the thumbnails of the galleries using highslide are without the caption below...

Is it possible to have the caption written below the thumbnails of the gallery?
how?